# Can I write my own version of go's http client.Do() function for my test cases?

Tags: unit-testing, go, overriding

I have a file, called user-service.go and the corresponding test file, called user-service_test.go. As I try to get complete code coverage, I am struggling to get some of the error conditions to actually happen.

Here is the function: GetOrCreateByAccessToken()

```
//GetOrCreateByAccessToken gets a user from the database with the given access token
func (s *service) GetOrCreateByAccessToken(aT string, client *Client) (*user.User, fcerr.FCErr) {

var currentUser user.OauthUser

req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://openidconnect.googleapis.com/v1/userinfo?access_token="+aT, nil)
if err != nil {
    return nil, fcerr.NewInternalServerError("Error when setting up the network request")
}

response, err := client.httpClient.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("error when getting the userinfo with the access token")
    return nil, fcerr.NewInternalServerError("Error when trying to verify user identity")
}

defer response.Body.Close()

contents, err := io.ReadAll(response.Body)
if err != nil {
    return nil, fcerr.NewInternalServerError("Error when trying to read response from Google about user identity")
}
```

The main control I have for my tests is that I can pass in a *Client.

Here is the part of the test case where I'd like to have io.ReadAll throw an error:

```
h := http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    //manually return the message google would return on an actual request
    w.Write([]byte(googleAPIOKResponse))
})
//Call the testHTTPClient() function defined in the test file to substitute my own HandlerFunc
httpClient, teardown := testHTTPClient(h)
defer teardown()

//Call the real NewClient() from my user-service.go
client := NewClient()

//Substitute the default httpClient for the one I've just set up.
client.httpClient = httpClient

resultingUser, err := userService.GetOrCreateByAccessToken(nU.AccessToken, client)

assert.Nil(t, resultingUser)
assert.NotNil(t, err)
assert.Equal(t, http.StatusInternalServerError, err.Status())
```

Is there somewhere I can write my own version of the .Do() method which will put something in the response which will cause io.ReadAll to return an error? Or is there a better way to achieve the error with just the pre-baked response text I'm already using?

Comment: Dependency injection and test doubles are easy in Go, because of the way interfaces work. You can always create your own interface type that `*http.Client` satisfies: `type Client interface { Do(*http.Request) (*http.Response, error) }`. Then you can create your own test double that satisfies your `Client` interface but, contrary to `http.Client`, operates only in memory and returns some canned response for testing purposes. This post by Mat Ryer is a good starting point: https://medium.com/@matryer/5-simple-tips-and-tricks-for-writing-unit-tests-in-golang-619653f90742

Comment: You can use this package: https://pkg.go.dev/net/http/httptest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a way to replace the Do method, but there is a way to accomplish your goal.

Create a [round tripper](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#RoundTripper) type that returns an arbitrary response body:

```
type respondWithReader struct{ body io.Reader }

func (rr respondWithReader) RoundTrip(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
    return &http.Response{
        Proto:      "HTTP/1.0",
        ProtoMajor: 1,
        Header:     make(http.Header),
        Close:      true,
        Body:       ioutil.NopCloser(rr.body),
    }, nil

}
```

Create an io.Reader that fails:

```
var errReadFail = errors.New("blah!")

type failReader int

func (failReader) Read([]byte) (int, error) {
    return 0, errReadFail
}
```

Use the stock client with the transport and reader above:

```
c := http.Client{Transport: respondWithReader{body: failReader(0)}}
resp, err := c.Get("http://whatever.com")
if err != nil {
    t.Error(err)
}
defer resp.Body.Close()

// ReadAll returns errReadFail
_, err = ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
if err != errReadFail {
    t.Errorf("got err %v, expect %v", err, errReadFail)
}
```

[Run the test on the Go playground](https://go.dev/play/p/-nq3AbspPix).

Comment: I'd had the idea to create a Reader that fails, but I didn't know how to get that reader involved, so the RoundTripper bit was exactly what I needed! Thank you!!